# Javascript Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a directory, then create a file in this directory, then I'm trying to delete the directory. If I'm running the functions one by one, the code is working, but when I'm running them together I get this error :

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\tw\test\test.txt'] {   errno: -4058,   code:
> 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
> 'C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\tw\test\test.txt' }

Also if I'm running only the first 2 functions, everything works fine. What's wrong with my code?

```
const rimraf = require("rimraf");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const fs = require("fs");
const err1 = new Error("File Error!");
const err2 = new Error("Directory deleting Error!");

function createDirectory() {
    mkdirp("./test");
}
function createFile() {
    fs.writeFile("./test/test.txt", "this is my text", function (err1) {
        if (err1) throw err1;
        console.log("Results Received");
    });
}
function deleteDirectory() {
    rimraf("./test", function (err2) {
        if (err2) console.log(err2);
        console.log("Succesfully deleted a directory");
    });
}

function main() {
    createDirectory();
    createFile();
    deleteDirectory();
}
main();
```

Comment: Each one of those functions runs async, not one after each other.

Answer (score 2):

Those functions are async. You'll need to use some [`Promise` logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make them chain:

```js
const rimraf = require("rimraf");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const fs = require("fs");
const err1 = new Error("File Error!");
const err2 = new Error("Directory deleting Error!");

function createDirectory() {
    return mkdirp("./test");
}
function createFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fs.writeFile("./test/test.txt", "this is my text", function (err1) {
        if (err1) throw err1;
        console.log("Results Received");

        resolve();
      });
   });
}
function deleteDirectory() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      rimraf("./test", function (err2) {
        if (err2) console.log(err2);
        console.log("Succesfully deleted a directory");
       
        resolve();
      });
   });
}

function main() {
    createDirectory()
    .then(() => {
        return createFile();
    })
    .then() => {
       return deleteDirectory();
    });
}
main();
```

Comment: You used in createDirectory() function `return mkdirp("./test");`.
Does it have a behavior like a promise? Because it wouldn't work without that "return" in the main function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these packages. I checked [`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) and it returns a promise. So you just need to return the promise it returns. The other functions don't return promises so you need to create a new one and return that.

Comment: Oh, that's it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`mkdirp`, `writeFile`, and `rimraf` ar all **asynchronous**, but you're not waiting for earlier ones to finish before you ask the later ones to start.

I'd suggest using an `async` functoin and the promise-enabled versions of those ([`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) is already promise-enabled, use [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options) from `fs/promises`, and there has to be a promise wrapper for `rimraf` now; if not, use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal)). Then you could use `await`:

```
async function main() {
    await createDirectory();
    await createFile();
    await deleteDirectory();
}
```

where (for example) `createFile` is:

```
const {writeFile} = require('fs/promises');
// ...
async function createFile() {
    await writeFile("./test/test.txt", "this is my text");
    console.log("Results Received");
}
```